# Widgets next to each other same size in Qt

Tags: qt, layout

I have two widgets, one arbitrary (usually a QLineEdit), and one QLabel which displays a Pixmap. They are placed next to each other with a QHBoxLayout. The widget with this layout is in turn placed in another layout.

Now, what I want is that the label with the pixmap is automatically resized so that it is as high as the arbitrary widget next to it. However, even when I set the label's sizePolicy to Maximum, it still seems to expand to the  original pixmap size, instead of resizing the pixmap and shrinking to match the other widget. Instead of having two equally large widgets I have the arbitrary one which is smaller than the pixmap next to it.

Any ideas how to get the size of the pixmap label to match the size of the widget next to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
int height = arbitraryWidget->height();             // get desired height.

label->setSizeHint(QSize(label->width(), height);   // set size hint to current width and desired height.
label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed);           // optional, but this ensures size is desired.
```

Comment: Thanks. Where could I put this so that it is automatically called when the size of the arbitrary widget is changed? There doesn't seem to be any signal for that.

Comment: I believe emitting a signal from your arbitrary widget's resizeEvent() method would do the job. Then your parent window could connect that signal to a slot with this code.